# Run ant build.xml from custom eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, ant, build.xml

I am creating an Eclipse plugin to automatically import a large number of projects into Eclipse. Once the import is completed, I would like to build them using build.xml from plugin itself. I am new to plugin creation. Could anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

As a starter you might want to look [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0502_gawor/0502_gawor.html)

```
File buildFile = new File("build.xml");
Project project = new Project();
project.setUserProperty("ant.file", buildFile.getAbsolutePath());
project.init();
ProjectHelper helper = ProjectHelper.getProjectHelper();
project.addReference("ant.projectHelper", helper);
helper.parse(project, buildFile);
project.executeTarget(p.getDefaultTarget());
```

The above is a basic version of the article. I've used this method to ant run a build.xml from my plugin.